# I have 2 tables election (post,area) & I hae declared

Tags: java, sockets

I have got the client and server programs (from internet) for socket programming. They work well for the localhost connection & also for different machines on same LAN network.But,I want to try the same on different machines in different networks. (windows or ubuntu preferable). Please help me out.

Comment: And what exactly does not work?

Comment: Every book in Java Network programming is a valid answer to a question like this! Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then ask an exact question.